# Meteor Routing and subsequent data order

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I got stuck at understanding Meteor Routes and data flow.

In the beginning it was simple blog app, with 1 collection named `Posts`.

Now I want to store history of changes, so I've created a second collection and named it `History`.

On every edit in `Posts` I'm adding state of post (author,content, etc ...) to `History` including the ID of edited post.

Question is how should I configure Iron Router to make it pass the current post id to `posts/:_id/history` from previous state (`posts/:_id/`) and get entries from `History` with this matching ID?

Answer (score 2):

To pass the id from one view to the next, you can do it via template like so:

```
<a href="/posts/1/history>Post History</a>
```

or

```
<a href="/posts/{{_id}}/history>Post History</a>
```

or programmatically like so:

```
Router.go('postHistory', {_id: 1});
```

To get the history entries, you can resolve the data in iron router during the route request as so:

```
this.route('postHistory', {
  path: '/posts/:_id/history',
  data: function() {
    return History.findOne({postId: this.params._id});
  }
});
```

Comment: i've used to have the same code, but it just returns everything. At what this.params._id is pointing to ? And do you know how to check current "this" id of document at opened page in browser console (like Collection.find(this.??) ?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code it is hard to tell what you have tried already. But in order to help you understand Meteor routes perhaps you could take a look at these two links:

- [This introduction to routes with Iron Router](http://meteortips.com/second-meteor-tutorial/iron-router-part-1/)
- [This link on more advanced routes](http://meteortips.com/second-meteor-tutorial/iron-router-part-2/)

These should help you comprehend how to make two collections work together.

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to click the green check to accept the answer if it was helpful